# python cannot install tensorflow

Tags: python

My PC is 64 bit and python version is 3.7.9. I installed tensorflow as following. Does anyone know how to solve it? Let me know if further information is needed.
[image]

**Edit:**

I also tried anaconda as follow:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tensorflow/tensorflow_installation.htm

But the problem is that in anaconda prompt, I can import tensorflow. I use python in visual studio 2017. When I open python file in VS, it seems different with anaconda prompt. Do you know how to make it also work in VS?

Comment: `python -m pip install tensorflow`

Comment: @sahasrara62 same error

Comment: @eshirvana same error

Comment: are you using the private network (company laptop)or public one (own laptop) ?  otherwise download a  whl distributed file and install from that

Comment: @sahasrara62 it is my personal computer and I can install anything I want. Do you mean `tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`? I tried and showed the error in the above picture.

Comment: @sahasrara62 pls see my update

Comment: dont know why it is not installing in windows, but to change the python interpreter you need to add the python path of the anaconda to the vs code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Python your using is too new for the version of TensorFlow your using.

If you go here: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.13.1/, and look on the left hand side and scroll down to "Programming Language", you will see the latest python version on that list is Python 3.6.

That is the cause of error your getting. You can either:

- Switch to Python 3.6 or
- Use TensorFlow 1.14.0 or above which supports Python 3.7

Also make sure your using the 64-bit version of Python. TensorFlow will not install if you have the 32-bit version of Python installed.

Comment: I tried `pip install tensorflow==1.14.0` and got the same error.

Comment: Do you know if your python is the 32 or 64 bit version? It needs to be the 64-bit version.

Comment: you are right, I incorrectly used the python 32 bit. Now everything works. I installed tensorflow 2.7. So I needn't install Keras, right?

Comment: Yes, with TensorFlow 2.x, you can use tf.keras included with TensorFlow

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:
pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: sorry, I got the same error.